# laravel pivot table with nullable foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a pivot table set up as follows:

```
user_roles
  user_id //fk->users.id
  assoc_id //nullable fk->association.id
  role //varchar
```

I set my database up this way because roles represent a many to many relationship: an association has many users, and a user may be in many associations.  every user has a role within an association.

However, there are some roles that exist that can exist outside of an association.  The database is configured to accept a null value in the `assoc_id` field and I can manually insert one from the command line, but when I attempt to execute

```
$user->roles()->attach(NULL, "outside contractor");
```

in my seed file, I get an error saying

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update   
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`user_roles`, CONSTR  
AINT `user_roles_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users  
` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `user_roles` () values ())
```

this is particularly confusing because shouldn't the first argument here be referring to the `assoc_id`?  When I replace the `NULL` with a valid `assoc_id`,

```
$user->roles()->attach(1, "outside contractor");
```

the insert works fine, and the first argument refers to the `assoc_id` in the table.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't provie a key/keys for `attach`/`sync`, Eloquent will not insert anything. It's rather expected behaviour, since what you are trying to do is:

*Create a link between X and null*

this is not what ORM is supposed to do.

Instead insert those rows manually:

```
$data = [
   'user_id' => 99, 
   'assoc_id' => null, 
   'role' => 'outside contractor'
];

DB::table('user_roles')->insert($data);
```

Comment: Understood.  Hypothetically, If I were to create [a separate model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959112/creating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-laravel-with-additional-data/24959256#24959256) for my pivot, could it be done using Eloquent and `UserRole::create(['user_id'=>$user->id,'assoc_id'=>null,'outside contractor']);` or would that still be invalid?

Comment: Yes, that would work of course, as long as DB schema allows that. Read my previous comment as 'it can't be done with relations' rather than Eloquent.

Comment: Does `Model::create()` require timestamp fields?  I got an error stating `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into 'user_roles' ('user_id', 'assoc_id', 'role', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (100, , Outside Contractor, 2014-07-29 14:12:28, 2014-07-29 14:12:28))`

Comment: Every Eloquent model by default requires them. Set `public $timestamps = false;` on your model.